# Scope problem - put intent extra and start activity from 2 different functions

Tags: java, android

I have 2 listeners, 1 needs to get the intent extra, which is an image uri, and the other one needs to start the other activity with that extra.
But I think that due to them being in different scopes, the extra is not really put for the intent that starts the other activity.

This is the code:

```
        private Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final Button button= findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), OtherActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == Thing.SPECIFIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Thing.ActivityResult result = Thing.getActivityResult(data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                    intent.putExtra("imageUri", resultUri.toString());    
                }
           }
   }
```

I want that the extra that I put in `onActivityResult` will be sent to the activity started by the `onClickListener` when the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion is to use a field to store the image URI :

1- define a String variable in your class

```
String imageURI = "";
```

2- in your onActivityResult :

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == Thing.SPECIFIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Thing.ActivityResult result = Thing.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                imageURI = resultUri.toString();    
            }
       }
```

3-in your onClickListener :

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageURI);    
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this at first, but then the activity won't start at all

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick` you are re-initializing the Intent, so any extras you may have set are lost. If you remove the line above `startActivity` you should be fine.

I would not go that way thought. I would not have the Intent as a class variable but rather the image URI. So whenever a click event happens, I would check for the image URI having been set, create a new Intent and then start the Activity.

Your code would become like this:

```
private String intentImage = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (intentImage != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageUri", intentImage); 

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Thing.SPECIFIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Thing.ActivityResult result = Thing.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            intentImage = resultUri.toString();    
        }
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that you don't have any `startActivityForResult` in your code. So if this is your full activity, you would never get `onActivityResult` invoked.

Comment: I tried this at first, but then the activity won't start at all, can you show me in code what you mean please?

Comment: @Fireio have a look